# C++ regex_match not working

Tags: c++, regex, c++11

Here is part of my code

```
bool CSettings::bParseLine ( const char* input )
{
    //_asm INT 3


    std::string line ( input );
    std::size_t position = std::string::npos, comment;

    regex cvarPattern ( "\\.([a-zA-Z_]+)" );
    regex parentPattern ( "^([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)\\." );
    regex cvarValue ( "\\.[a-zA-Z0-9_]+[ ]*=[ ]*(\\d+\\.*\\d*)" );
    std::cmatch matchedParent, matchedCvar;


    if ( line.empty ( ) )
        return false;

    if ( !std::regex_match ( line.c_str ( ), matchedParent, parentPattern ) )
        return false;

    if ( !std::regex_match ( line.c_str ( ), matchedCvar, cvarPattern ) )
        return false;
...
}
```

I try to separate with it lines which I read from file - lines look like:

```
foo.bar = 15
baz.asd = 13
ddd.dgh = 66
```

and I want to extract parts from it - e.g. for 1st line foo.bar = 15, I want to end up with something like:

```
a = foo
b = bar
c = 15
```

but now, regex is returning always false, I tested it on many online regex checkers, and even in visual studio, and it's working great, do I need some different syntax for C++ regex_match? I'm using visual studio 2013 community

Comment: What compiler and stdlib are you using?

Comment: you have to double escape backslashes

Comment: @HAL9000 aren't they properly escaped?

Comment: @HAL9000 I don't think he/she wants to match literal backslashes.

Comment: @StefanoSanfilippo totally forgot about this, I edited question - I'm using visual studio 2013

Comment: @mlgpro Well, `regex` also needs to escape backslashes. The cleanest way to write regular expression strings in c++ is using [raw string literals](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal).

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ but I escaped them - haven't I? e.g. if I want \d in regular expression I write \\d in string, am I wrong?

Comment: try to take a look here http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=2064649&seqNum=2

Comment: It doesn't affect anything, but why are you using `.c_str()`? `regexp_match` can take `std::string` directly.

Comment: @mlgpro Why do you need this variables - cvarPattern and parentPattern?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The problem is that [std::regex_match](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/regex_match) must match the entire string but you are trying to match only part of it.

You need to either use [std::regex_search](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/regex_search) or alter your regular expression to match all three parts at once:

```
#include <regex>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

const auto test =
{
      "foo.bar = 15"
    , "baz.asd = 13"
    , "ddd.dgh = 66"
};

int main()
{
    const std::regex r(R"~(([^.]+)\.([^\s]+)[^0-9]+(\d+))~");
    //                     (  1  )  (   2  )       ( 3 ) <- capture groups

    std::cmatch m;

    for(const auto& line: test)
    {
        if(std::regex_match(line, m, r))
        {
            // m.str(0) is the entire matched string
            // m.str(1) is the 1st capture group
            // etc...
            std::cout << "a = " << m.str(1) << '\n';
            std::cout << "b = " << m.str(2) << '\n';
            std::cout << "c = " << m.str(3) << '\n';
            std::cout << '\n';
        }
    }
}
```

Regular expression: https://regex101.com/r/kB2cX3/2

**Output:**

```
a = foo
b = bar
c = 15

a = baz
b = asd
c = 13

a = ddd
b = dgh
c = 66
```

Answer (score 4):

To focus on `regex` patterns I'd prefer to use [raw string literals](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal) in c++:

```
regex cvarPattern ( R"rgx(\.([a-zA-Z_]+))rgx" );
regex parentPattern ( R"rgx(^([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)\.)rgx" );
regex cvarValue ( R"rgx(\.[a-zA-Z0-9_]+[ ]*=[ ]*(\d+\.*\d*))rgx" );
```

Everything between the `rgx(` `)rgx` delimiters doesn't need any extra escaping for c++ char literal characters.

---

Actually what you have written in your question resembles to those regular expressions I've been writing as raw string literals.
You probably simply meant something like

```
regex cvarPattern ( R"rgx(.([a-zA-Z_]+))rgx" );
regex parentPattern ( R"rgx(^([a-zA-Z0-9_]+).)rgx" );
regex cvarValue ( R"rgx(.[a-zA-Z0-9_]+[ ]*=[ ]*(\d+(\.\d*)?))rgx" );
```

I didn't dig in deeper, but I'm not getting all of these escaped characters in your regular expression patterns now.

---

As for your question in the comment, you can use a choice of matching sub-pattern groups, and check for which of them was applied in the matches structure:

```
regex cvarValue ( 
   R"rgx(.[a-zA-Z0-9_]+[ ]*=[ ]*((\d+)|(\d+\.\d?)|([a-zA-Z]+)){1})rgx" );
                             // ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

You probably don't need these `cvarPattern` and `parentPattern` regular expressions to inspect other (more detailed) views about the matching pattern.

Comment: I added \. in my regex pattern, because there also may be float values, such as 2.5, and I probably made some mistakes, because I edited it 9000 times

Comment: @mlgpro You'll need to have a choice of groups like `(\d+)|(\d+\.\d?)|([a-zA-Z]+)` or so.