# Failing to match trivial regex

Tags: c++, regex, c++11

I am learning the how to use the regex library in C++. I implemented the example from http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/regex/regex_match/

```
std::string s( "subject" );
std::regex e( "(sub)(.*)" );

std::smatch sm;  
std::regex_match( s, sm, e );
std::cout << "string object with " << sm.size() << " matches\n";
```

which prints

```
string object with 3 matches
```

as expected. However, If I change the first lines to

```
std::string s( "Hello world!" );
std::regex e( "\\S+" );
```

I get

```
string object with 0 matches
```

Am I missing something obvious here, or is this a bug? I'm using gcc 5.4.0. (g++ --std=c++11).

Comment: `std::regex_match` has to match the **whole** string.

Comment: For the sake of future readers, regex is not implemented in libstdc++ 4.8 - i.e. GCC 4.8.0 is not fully C++11 compliant. Either upgrade libstdc++ or use the LLVM/Clang libc++ library instead.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30445048/c-regex-match-not-working

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C++ regex\_match not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30445048/c-regex-match-not-working)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think this is a problem with `\S`, but that `regex_match` must match the whole string, otherwise it will not match at all.

Try replacing the first two lines with this:

```
std::string s( "Hello world!" );
std::regex e( "\\S+ \\S+" );
```

If you want to match substrings, try `regex_search`:

```
std::string s( "Hello world!" );
std::regex e( "\\S+" );

std::smatch sm;

// Loop through matches
while (std::regex_search( s, sm, e )) {
    std::cout << "string object with " << sm.size() << " matches\n";
    // Replace current string with the remainder, otherwise this
    // will loop infinitely
    s = sm.suffix().str();
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I guess I was confused because the example yielded multiple matches.

Answer (score -1):

The C++ standard has a bunch of options which can be passed to the `regex` constructor. See [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/basic_regex) for the options. Some of them specify which grammar to use. Try the [ecmascript](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/ecmascript) one which has support for `\S`.

Something like:

```
std::regex e( "(sub)(.*)", std::regex::ECMAScript );
```

For example, the Extended syntax doesn't support `\S`. It's unclear to me which one is the default, but it's worth a shot to see if it's different than the ECMAScript one.

Comment: `ECMAScript` is used by default so that is not the problem here.