# Regex that does not accept sub strings of more than two 'b'

Tags: regex, regression

I need a regex that accepts all the strings consisting only of characters `a` and `b`, except those with more than two 'b' in a row.

For example, these should not match:

```
abb
ababbb
bba
bbbaa
bbb
bb
```

I came up with this, but it's not working

```
[a-b]+b{2,}[a-b]*
```

Here is my code:

```
int main() {
    string input;
    regex validator_regex("\b(?:b(?:a+b?)*|(?:a+b?)+)\b");
    
    cout << "Hello, "<<endl;
    while(regex_match(input,validator_regex)==false){
        cout << "please enter your choice of regEx :"<<endl;
        cin>>input;
        if(regex_match(input,validator_regex)==false)
            cout<<input+" is not a valid input"<<endl;
        else
            cout<<input+" is  valid "<<endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: You need what is known in regex as "look ahead" or "look behind". Look it up.

Comment: Try this [`\b(?!(?:a*b){2,})[ab]+\b`](https://regex101.com/r/HhWhtb/1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your pattern `[a-b]+b{2,}[a-b]*` matches 1 or more `a` or `b` chars until you match `bb` which is what you don't want. Also note that the string should be at least 3 characters long due to this part `[a-b]+b{2,}`

---

To not match 2 `b` chars in a row you can exclude those matches using a negative lookahead by matching optional chars a or b until you encounter `bb`

Note that `[a-b]` is the same as `[ab]`

```
\b(?![ab]*?bb)[ab]+\b
```

- `\b` A word boundary
- `(?![ab]*?bb)` Negative lookahead, assert not 0+ times `a` or `b` followed by `bb` to the right
- `[ab]+` Match 1+ occurrences of `a` or `b`
- `\b` A word boundary

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/0ZwdFF/1)

---

Without using lookarounds, you can match the strings that you don't want by matching a string that contains `bb`, and capture in group 1 the strings that you want to keep:

```
\b[ab]*bb[ab]*\b|\b([ab]+)\b
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/A9p7ul/1)

---

Or use an alternation matching either starting with `b` and optional repetitions of 1+ `a` chars followed by an optional `b`, or match 1+ repetitions of starting with `a` followed by an optional `b`

```
\b(?:b(?:a+b?)*|(?:a+b?)+)\b
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/7x6Ip7/1)

Comment: I didn't realise that the OP had asked to exclude consecutive `b` s(in a row). I guess this is the answer he/she is looking for..

Comment: thank you for your solution its correct but i think i'm not implementing it correctly \ it seems it should be working but any input i give is invalid , i've included my code in the question

Comment: @KiumarsChalangi If you want to match a part of the string, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30445048/c-regex-match-not-working using `regex_search` instead and / or double escape the backslashes `regex validator_regex("\\b(?:b(?:a+b?)*|(?:a+b?)+)\\b");`

Comment: @KiumarsChalangi See https://ideone.com/8gVHLi

Comment: totally solved my problem thank you sir

Answer (score 1):

The simplest regex is:

```
^(?!.*bb)[ab]+$
```

See [live demo](https://rubular.com/r/LtGBO7LX1vzopi).

This regex works by adding a negative look ahead (anchored to start) for `bb` appearing anywhere within input consisting of `a` or `b`.

If zero length input should match, change `[ab]+` to `[ab]*`.